# When uploading large video file Sitecore becomes unresponsive

Tags: experience-editor

when is uploading large video file Sitecore become unresponsive, and upload takes long time, but never finishes.

Comment: How large is the video file?

Comment: It is 462 mb file

Comment: https://iarpitkatiyar.com/2021/08/01/how-to-upload-large-files-in-sitecore/

Comment: Hi, I have setuped up this setting both on asp.net and Sitecore level for request upload bot for threshold of 500 mb.

Comment: Perhaps best to explore another option than using the database to store media items that large. Streaming is going to be a nightmare for performance.

Comment: My guess is you are timing out. 462mb is far too big of a file for the media library anyway, I would agree with Michael, use another option for that file.